# Can SnappyData load from s3 and save into s3?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snappydata

I found the website of SnappyData recently. I'm interested about SparkSQL query performance. Is there anybody who tried loading s3 and saving s3 operation with SnappyData ? I can't find such a document.

I want to use pyspark, and specify 'com.databricks.spark.csv' format and various options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can. [Here](https://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/reference/sql_reference/create-external-table/#example) is an example.